# Fullcalendar Qtips Date Format

Tags: date, format, fullcalendar, qtip2

I'm trying to get the event.end time to display correctly in pop-up qtip2 tooltips using the following code:

```
            element.qtip({
            content: {    
                title: { text: event.title },
                text: '<span class="qtip-title">Starts: </span>' + ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'h:mm a')) + '<br>' + '<span class="qtip-title">Ends: </span>' + event.end + '<br>' + '<span class="qtip-title">Venue: </span>' + event.location + '<br>' + '<span class="qtip-title">Description: </span>' + event.description
            },
            ...
```

The event start time displays correctly using the code:

```
($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'h:mm a'))
```

and the event end time displays as a string of numbers (ISO8601 string ?) using the code:

```
event.end
```

If I try replacing with either:

```
($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, 'h:mm a'))
```

or:

```
event.end.format('h:mm a ddd')
```

The calendar completely fails to display. Note: The code:     event.start.format('h:mm a ddd') also displays the start time correctly.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Further Update re: Console Log

Using the following code:

```
content: {    
                title: { text: event.title },
                text: '<span class="qtip-title">Starts: </span>' + event.start.format('h:mm a') + '<br>' + '<span class="qtip-title">Ends: </span>' + event.end.format('h:mm a') + '<br>' + '<span class="qtip-title">Venue: </span>' + event.location + '<br>' + '<span class="qtip-title">Description: </span>' + event.description
            },
...
```

the following console log data is returned:

```
unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]  js:69:1217
jQuery.Deferred exception: event.end is null eventRender@http://example.com/site/templates/scripts/hnu-calendar.js:80:66
H</t.prototype.publiclyTrigger@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:10:2065
p</e.prototype.publiclyTrigger@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:25413
o</t.prototype.filterEventRenderEl@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:7:29788
o</t.prototype.renderFgSegEls/<@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:7:29235
each@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:2813
each@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:1001
o</t.prototype.renderFgSegEls@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:7:29187
o</t.prototype.renderFgRanges@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:7:27940
o</t.prototype.render@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:7:27699
p</e.prototype.executeEventRender@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:26656
p</e.prototype.callChildren/<@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:31088
p</e.prototype.iterChildren@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:31182
p</e.prototype.callChildren@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:31058
p</e.prototype.executeEventRender@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:26729
p</e.prototype.requestEventsRender/<@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:7:18403
o</e.prototype.runTask@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:23735
r</t.prototype.runRemaining@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:22352
r</t.prototype.tryStart@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:22182
r</t.prototype.resume@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:9:21984
p</e.prototype.stopBatchRender@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:7:15515
e@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:6:16679
dispatch@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:10263
add/q.handle@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:8325
trigger@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:4:5806
triggerHandler@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:4:6394
s</e.prototype.trigger@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:6:16925
a</e.prototype.setProps@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:8:4635
a</e.prototype.set@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:8:4028
a</e.prototype.watch/this._watchers[t]</<@http://example.com/scripts-mx/fullcalendar.3.9.0.min.js:8:4864
j@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29946
g/</k<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262
undefined  jquery.min.js:2:31515
```

Followed subsequently by this output:

```
BackgroundThumbnails remote process crashed - recovering  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:256
Error: page-thumbnail:error  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:116:24
TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
BackgroundThumbnails remote process crashed - recovering  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:256
```

Error: page-thumbnail:error  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:116:24
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    BackgroundThumbnails remote process crashed - recovering  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:256
    Error: page-thumbnail:error  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:116:24
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    BackgroundThumbnails remote process crashed - recovering  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:256
    Error: page-thumbnail:error  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:116:24
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    BackgroundThumbnails remote process crashed - recovering  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:256
    Error: page-thumbnail:error  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:116:24
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    TelemetryStopwatch: requesting elapsed time for nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_1ST_RESULT_TIME_MS", key: "null" TelemetryStopwatch.jsm:363
    BackgroundThumbnails remote process crashed - recovering  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:256
    Error: page-thumbnail:error  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:116:24
    BackgroundThumbnails remote process crashed - recovering  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:256
    Error: page-thumbnail:error  BackgroundPageThumbs.jsm:116:24
    An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing  container.html:8
    An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing  container.html:8
    An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing  container.html:8
    a: timer startedsca.17.4.72.js:32
    a: 0.84mssca.17.4.72.js:32
    WebRTC interfaces with the “moz” prefix (mozRTCPeerConnection, mozRTCSessionDescription, mozRTCIceCandidate) have been deprecated.  sca.17.4.72.js:33:4653
    This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!  edit

The first line refers to https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=....
The first part of the second line ... hnu-calendar.js:80:66 Line 66 of that file refers to the second line of the following code:

```
        bootstrapFontAwesome: {
        close: 'fa-times',
        prev: 'fa-angle-left',
        next: 'fa-angle-right',
        prevYear: 'fa-angle-double-left',
        nextYear: 'fa-angle-double-right'
    },
```

The net result is a blank calendar and if I simply remove the following from the content section:

```
'<span class="qtip-title">Ends: </span>' + event.end.format('h:mm a') + '<br>' +
```

The calendar diplays fine albeit the ends time is missing from the pop-up qtip tooltips.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Yes. I'll have to edit the original question as the output is too long for a comment.

Comment: Some of that doesn't strike me as directly related. But...is it possible that one or more of your events doesn't actually have a stated end date? That might cause it to fail to format it

Comment: P.s. don't worry the question is the right place for error messages, that kind of info should always be in the question, never the comments. Comments are just for discussion

Comment: All the calendar entries for 4 of the 5 calendars had from and to times entered apart from one entry that is an all day event. The other calendar I managed by a separate group so I've left a message with them to check. In the meantime I tried removing the var for that event source and refreshing the page and it made no difference.

Comment: I now see the issue is being caused due to: Deferred exception: event.end is null eventRender

Comment: Setting the all day event to private to exclude it did not resolve the issue, btw.

Comment: AFAIK Fullcalendar has no concept of private events, so not sure what you mean by that. Anyway I think all you need to do is test whether event.end is null before trying to call the .format() method on it.

Comment: The one calendar I do not have any control over the content is displayed on a separate subsite that I can control and same error occurs. Instead of removing the var for that calendar on the main website I tried removing the event source. It does look like that fifth calendar data does contain missing end dates and is what is causing the issue. Many thanks for your assistance, once again.